# Why doesn't python have a attrsetter (and what would it take to make one)?

Tags: python

`operator` provides `attrgetter` to make a function that retrieves a field from an object.

Why isn't this included in  `operator` (or somewhere else in the standard libraries)?

```
def attrsetter(name):
    def setter( obj, val):
        setattr(obj, name, val)
    return setter
```

The only reason that I can think of is that there are edge cases where this straightforward approach will break.  In which case, what are these edge cases so that I can try to trap/avoid them?

Comment: `itemsetter` is missing too. My bet is that it isn't as useful as the getter counterparts so they didn't add it.

Comment: Maybe they just don't see many use cases.  Normally these operators return a value so they can be used functionally, e.g. with `map`, `filter`, etc.  Setting something typically returns `None`.

Comment: Also, since `attrgetter` provides fancy stuff allowing more attributes and dotted names, you probably want to create a symmetric setter able to set multiple attributes with dotted names.

Comment: @Bakuriu it's actually called [`setitem`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.setitem) to be coherent with `__setitem__`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`attrgetter` is designed to be used in places where a function is required as a replacement for `lambda`. For example:

```
# equivalent
heads = map(attrgetter('head'), objs)
heads = map(lambda o: o.head, objs)
```

In other words, the point of `attrgetter` is to create a side-effect-free function that returns a useful value, and which can be used in expressions that require a function. An `attrsetter`, on the other hand, would only operate by side effect, and would need to return `None` by Python convention. Since `attrsetter` would not be at all useful as argument to `map` and similar, it is not provided. If you need `attrsetter`, simply write a normal `for` loop.

Also note that both of the above idioms are better expressed with a list comprehension:

```
heads = [o.head for o in objs]
```

`attrgetter` is rarely needed and has lost much of its appeal once it was [decided](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2006-February/060415.html) that `lambda` would not be removed from Python 3 after all.

Comment: I think the side effect argument is kind of moot given the `operator` module provides `setitem` and `delitem`. Also I agree that most of the time `attrgetter` is better expressed through a comprehension but there's valid use cases for using the former. One of thing that makes `attrgetter` appealing over `lambda` is that the CPython ships a C implementation that is significantly faster in a hot loop and allows multiple attributes to be retrieved at once using `attrgetter(*attrs)`.

Comment: @SimonCharette I agree that the side effect is not essential. Based on when it appeared, I argued `attrgetter` was the result of the short-lived (and IMO misguided) attempt to rid Python of `lambda`. `lambda x: x.foo` was often cited as an example of `lambda`'s usefulness, so `attrgetter` was introduced to replace it. Since `setattr` was rarely used in lambdas, there was no need for an `attrsetter`. It's not a good reason not to have one in the future, just an explanation of why it wasn't added originally. If you need it, I think it makes sense to propose adding it on bugs.python.org.